# What is the x86 equivalent of VCVT instruction on ARM when converting between floating-point and fixed-point elements of a vector?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, arm, fixed-point

I am learning some assembly and was disassembling some ARM code and then I found this:

```
vcvt.s32.f32 q8, q8, #0xf
```

So I started going over the ARM reference manual and I am now struggling to find the equivalent instruction or another way of doing it on x86.

Comment: On x86 I believe you will first have to multiply by the scaling factor yourself.

Comment: X86 does not really have fixed point support.